# Spring Cloud Config Server returns extra backslash

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm writing a secret in Vault similar to `secret1=test1\ntest2` and use it inside a Spring Boot application configuration using `@Value("${secret1}")`. However, upon successful retrieval from Vault via Spring Cloud Config Server the `secret1` value is turned into `test1**\\n**test1`. So an extra backslash is added. It is a very small change that I would need to do in the application to remove that extra backslash, but I'd like to solve this the proper way. How can I prevent this extra backslash addition from happening?

Comment: I assume the `**` is just formatting you added to highligh the problem, right?

Comment: Yes indeed. The actual returned result is test1\\ntest1. Note the double backslash \\.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vault itself will not mess with the `\n`. Try this at the command line:

```
vault kv put secret/new-line secret1="test1\ntest2"
```

On the wire, it will be sent as this JSON:

```
{
  "data":{
    "secret": "test1\\ntest2"
  }
}
```

And getting the secret back brings the same value:

```
vault kv get --field data secret/new-line 
map[secret:test1\ntest2]
```

Your `\n` is probably interpreted as it is transformed in JSON and sent to Vault. Maybe whatever puts the secret in Vault does not use the same library/technology as your code?

Make sure that you escape the `\n` when it is saved in Vault. Getting it will bring back the `\n` unharmed.

Comment: So...my bad. The problem was indeed, that upon ingestion in Vault, the double backslash was being added and therefore a simple escaping before storing in Vault did the job.